# Убрать хештег из строки PHP

Tags: php, строки

Например есть строка

```
<?php 
$string = "#tag@footbal Последние новости прошедшего дня"
?>
```

Как можно избавить эту строку от тегов в будущем? Теги могут быть разными, но вид у них одинаковый: Решетка и какой-то текст до первого пробела.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написать шаблон, который будет соответствовать подстроке, начинающейся с символа `#`, за которым следуют любые символы, кроме пробела. Ну и пробельный символ тоже захватывать, чтоб лишних пробелов не было после удаления хеш-тегов:

```
$string = "#tag@footbal Последние новости прошедшего дня";

$string = preg_replace('~#\S+\s+~', '', $string);

echo $string;
```